# programming with matplotlib : plot() and draw()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using python3 with matplotlib. I've encountered some issues with the pyplot.draw() function : no graphic window appears on my screen when I run my script.

The pyplot.plot() function works just fine :

```
 #!/usr/bin/python3.2
 #-*-coding:utf-8-*

 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
 import numpy as np

 plt.figure(1)
 plt.plot(np.arange(35), np.arange(25),'r')
 plt.show()
```

In this situation ./myscript.py displays the graphic window.

But when I try to make an simple animation :

```
 import numpy as np
 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
 from time import sleep

 plt.ion()
 nb_images = 1000
 tableau = np.random.normal(10,10,(nb_images, 100, 100))
 image = plt.imshow(tableau[0,:,:])

 for k in np.arange(nb_images)
     image.set_data(tableau[k,:,:])
     print(k)
     plt.draw()
     sleep(0.1)
```

./myscript.py does the calculation (my terminal displays the "k" value) but the graphic window doesn't appear on my screen...

The problem is the same when I'm using python2.x

The backend in the configuration file "matplotlibrc" (python3.2) is "tkagg". I've already tried to change it but still no graphic window to admire my animation....

Thanks for you help.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, either in an interactive session or as a script. Using python 2.7.3, matplotlib 1.1.1 (a bit old but that's what the ubuntu repos got on this machine), and TKAgg backend, I see an animation of noisy images as expected.

Comment: use `plt.pause` instead of `sleep`